# Changing read-only field value with method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have a working GridView in an ASP.Net webapp which tracks DNS records I have requested. It's defined as follows:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvExistingEntries" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="DNSId" DataSourceID="dsDNS" Width="100%" 
    BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" 
    CellPadding="4" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" AllowSorting="True" ShowFooter="true">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DNSId" Visible="false" ReadOnly="true" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="DNSName" HeaderText="DNS Name" SortExpression="DNSName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="IPAddress" HeaderText="IP Address" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="IPAddress" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RecordType" HeaderText="Record Type" SortExpression="RecordType" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RequestTicket" HeaderText="Request Ticket" SortExpression="RequestTicket" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastUpdateBy" HeaderText="Updated By" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LastUpdateBy" />

        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="false" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="updateButton" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" Text="Update" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteButton" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" onClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this entry?');" />
            </ItemTemplate>

            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="saveUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Update" Text="Save" onClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to save these changes?');" />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="cancelUpdate" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FBFBF2" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#848384" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#EAEAD3" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#575357" />
</asp:GridView>
```

The datasource is defined as follows:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsDNS" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DNSMonConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [DNSId], [DNSName], [RecordType], [StartValidityDate], [EndValidityDate], [IPAddress], [LastUpdate], [RequestTicket], (select [FirstName] + ' ' + [LastName] + ' (' + [Login] + ')' FROM [User] where [User].[UserID] = [DomainName].[LastUpdateBy]) AS [LastUpdateBy] FROM [DomainName] ORDER BY [DNSName]"

    UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    UpdateCommand="sp_update_DNSEntry" OnUpdating
    DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"
    DeleteCommand="sp_drop_DNSEntry">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="DNSId" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="DNSId" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="DNSName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RecordType" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="IPAddress" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="RequestTicket" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Whenever the user uses the update feature this works and saves it to the database, but I want the code to resolve the IP address before it saves it. I have the method ready to go for this, but I do not know how to incorporate that into the code.

I'd rather avoid having the code on the database if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the IP address before the update by using the [`OnUpdating`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.updating.aspx) event.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource OnUpdating="OnSqlUpdating"
    ... etc />
```

In the handler code, get the [Command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasourcecommandeventargs.command.aspx) property from SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs, and update the appropriate parameter.

```
private void OnSqlUpdating(Object source, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e) 
{
    DbCommand command = e.Command;
    command.Parameters["IPAddress"] = Request.UserHostAddress;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dbaseman. Are you saying that before the GridView does an update, I also issue another update for the IP address? Does this mean basically two updates sql queries will be fired off at the database? Updating is not showing up as an option though. All I see is UpdateCommandType (which is presently set to StoredProcedure) and UpdateCommand which is set to the stored procedure name.

Comment: @flipcode no, just one SQL query.  The `OnSqlUpdating` event is a hook that lets you inspect and modify the parameters before it gets sent to the database.

Comment: I do not see Updating as a public property. I get this compile error:

Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource' does not have a public property named 'Updating'.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. I actually worked that out, but now I get this: **Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.dns_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'OnSqlUpdating' and no extension method 'OnSqlUpdating' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.dns_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Comment: @flipcode so it can't find the method ... is `OnSqlUpdating` defined inside a `script runat="server"` block, or in code behind?

Comment: OK the OnSQLUpdating needed to be protected rather than private, so it's now firing off. The value is being updated though. Here's the code:
    protected void OnSqlUpdating(Object source, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        string sIPAddresses = "10.0.0.1";
        
        DbCommand dbCmd = e.Command;
        dbCmd.Parameters["@IPAddress"].Equals(sIPAddresses);
    }

Comment: does the above make any sense?

Comment: @flipcode have to use =.  "equals". Doesn't do anything, it's just a comparer

Comment: OK so I had to change it to have `dbCmd.Parameters["@IPAddress"].Value = sIPAddresses;`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, the code to achieve this is:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsDNS" runat="server" OnUpdating="OnSqlUpdating" ... />

protected void OnSqlUpdating(Object source, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
    string sIPAddresses = "";

    // Custom code here to look up IP addresses.

    DbCommand dbCmd = e.Command;
    dbCmd.Parameters["@IPAddress"].Value = sIPAddresses;
}
```